# Powershell command to find employee number and update business unit

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to write a powershell script that will first import from a CSV file. The CSV file will contain the AD employee number attribute, and also the business unit attribute.

The script needs to find the AD user based on employee number attribute from the CSV, then update the business unit attribute for that user also contained in the CSV file. CSV will look like:

```
0,1
8022651,Sales & Marketing
```

So far I have been able to lookup the employee number using this:

```
$EmployeeNumber='8022651'
get-ADUser -Filter {EmployeeNumber -eq $EmployeeNumber}
```

I know I can use Import-CSV, but don't know how to piece it all together. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First we need to get the contents of the csv like so

`Import-Csv "path to your csv"`

If the business unit is located in the Office field we can update it with `set-aduser` like so

`% { set-aduser $_.0 -Office $_.1 }`

The `%` is short for `foreach-object`, what this essentially does is grab each user one at a time and change the Office field in AD

if we put `$_` into a pipeline it will get the previous information passed through so in this case we're grabbing the "0" and "1" headers from the CSV

Once the users Office has been changed it's nice to see each change so we can use `write-host` like so

`write-host "Changed the office of $($_.0) to $($_.1)`

Once again we are using `$_.0` and `$_.1` to get the headings from `Import-Csv` but because `write-host` is based on a string we have to put variables into `$( )` for them to display correctly.

Put together it is:

`Import-Csv "path to your csv" | % {set-ADUser $_.0 -Office $_.1; write-host "Changed the office of $($_.0) to $($_.1)}`

This will

```
Grab the information from your CSV
->then change info in Active Directory for each person based on the 0 and 1 headers
-->then write on the screen who it changed and what to
```

I hope this made sense, if not let me know in the comments below.

EDIT:

```
$csv = Import-Csv "path to your csv"
foreach($usr in $csv) {
    get-ADUser -Filter {EmployeeNumber -eq $usr.0} | set-ADUser $_ -Office $usr.1
}
```

EDIT 2:

```
$csv = Import-Csv "path to your csv"
foreach($usr in $csv) {
    $usrToEdit = $usr.0
    $editUsr = Get-ADUser -Filter {EmployeeNumber -eq $usrToEdit}
    set-aduser -Identity $editUsr.SamAccountName -Office $usr.1
}
```

Comment: OK I am getting this: set-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: '8022651'

Comment: Looks like set-ADUser is trying to find user, the '8022651' in the CSV is the employee number. I have to find users using only employeeNumber from CSV, then change the business area value

Comment: Ah sorry about that i think i forgot to get the user by employee ID first, totally my mistake. I've posted an edit that could work, please let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for that Bluecakes. It's close, now getting this.                                                                                                                                Set-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Supply a non-null argument and try the 
command again.
At line:3 char:65
+     get-ADUser -Filter {EmployeeNumber -eq $usr.0} | set-ADUser $_ -Office $usr. ...
+                                                                 ~~

Comment: I believe i have `nailed it`, please see Edit 2. I don't think Set-ADUser was getting the right information it needed hence the identity being null error.

Sorry it took me a couple of tries i'm quite new to powershell myself but very eager to help.

Comment: Na it has quite a few errors now, I think the get-ADUser -Filter still needs to apply. I'll keep working on it. Thanks for your help Bluecakes, I am still learning myself too.

Comment: You are completely right, i forgot to include your filter in EDIT 2 so that wouldn't have worked, i've updated EDIT 2 to include your filter so hopefully it should now work. -fingers crossed-

Comment: This is what I get: Get-ADUser: Get-ADUser : Property: '0' not found in object of type: 'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject'.
At line:3 char:16
+     $editUsr = Get-ADUser -Filter {EmployeeNumber -eq $usr.0}
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Property: '0' not found in object of type: 'System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject'.,Mic 
   rosoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser

Comment: I'm not sure why it says that the property 0 doesnt exist but we can always try setting the value of 0 to a variable and referencing the variable. I've updated EDIT 2

Comment: Appreciate your help with this very much Bluecakes. Now getting this: Get-ADUser : The search filter cannot be recognized
At line:4 char:16
+     $editUsr = Get-ADUser -Filter {EmployeeNumber -eq $usrToEdit}
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The search filter cannot be recognized,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUse 
   r

Comment: Oh i recognize that error, most commonly occurs when theres a space or a blank line between information in the csv file.